# Basic stuff about preg match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

So, I want to change @ sign from this preg match:

```
[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]{3,65}\.[A-Z]{2,4}
```

to (at) string, how make this work ;/ cant figure out.

Comment: Do you want `preg_replace`? Show some examples. What have you tried so far?

Comment: this preg match finds mail adress. I just want to change @ sign to (at) string, because I have different notation in some file. I know its noobish question but i gotta do it right now ;/

Comment: @SandMan: As the @ sign is in there only *once*, you can just use a standard string replace. Just FYI.

Comment: I don't have direct access to this file/1000s of files. Downloading them would be bigger stupidity than this question ;) I just want to change this @ - constant element to (at) constant string in this preg_match statement.

Comment: @SandMan: Not possible with `preg_match()` but [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace).

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for

[ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/6U6Y3q)

```
$your_string = str_replace('@', '(at)', $your_string);
```

or

```
if(preg_match("/[A-Z0-9._%+-]+(@|\(at\))[A-Z0-9.-]{3,65}\.[A-Z]{2,4}/i", $your_string)){}
```

Comment: [A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]{3,65}.[A-Z]{2,4} is working well for adress like idiot@idiot.com, but i want to run this preg_match for adress like : idiot(at)idiot.com Don't know how to figure it out, time is runinig ;/

Comment: I've figured it out by myself, thats my solution:                       [A-Z0-9._%+-]+(.(at.))[A-Z0-9.-]{3,65}\.[A-Z]{2,4}

Comment: You just need to replace `@` with `\(at\)` - the slashes are important. Without them, the parens mean "capture this" rather than "match some parans". In your version in your comment, the dots are matching the parans, but it means your regexp will also match `foo!at!bar.com`

Comment: @Cal so pretty much what my example has above.

Comment: Yes, but with an explanation as to *why*. I upvoted your answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to create groups and in your replacement, refer to these (backreferences).

```
search:  ([A-Z0-9._%+-]+)@([A-Z0-9.-]{3,65}.[A-Z]{2,4})
         `-- group #1 --´ `-------- group #2 ---------´

replace: \1(at)\2
```